# Split string using multi-character delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a text using delimiters that can be longer than one symbol.

For example, this should be split using `and`, `or` and comma:

`"red lorry, yellow lorry and brown lorry".split(someRegexp)`

should produce:

`["red lorry", " yellow lorry", "brown lorry"]`

It's not necessary for regex to trim spaces, this can be done later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
/,|\b\s*(?:and|or)\s*\b/
```

**Example**

```
> "red lorry, yellow lorry and brown lorry".split(/,|\b\s*(?:and|or)\s*\b/)
< ["red lorry", " yellow lorry", "brown lorry"]
```

- `\b` Matches word boundaries. This ensure that the `or` and `and` are not matched within another word.

Comment: No, the correct placement of the word boundaries is `/,|\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*/`.

Comment: Why do you think that @WiktorStribiżew? Your regex just has another meaning.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Isn't the intent to match `or` and `and` as whole words? If yes, I think it is appropriate to place the word boundaries around the grouping construct. Otherwise, some spaces [might remain](https://regex101.com/r/yO7kI0/1).